# How does the categorical definition of a product apply to the arithmetical product?

Tags: category-theory

If object $X$ and morphisms $p_1 : X \to X_1, p_2 : X \to X_2$ define the product of objects $X_1, X_2$ in category $C$, how do we map this construction to arithmetical multiplication? What are the objects and morphisms in $C$? What items can we identify with the objects and morphisms involved in this product?

Comment: Besides the name, why do you think it should have anything to do with arithmetical multiplication?

Comment: In the category of sets, the cardinality of the product of two (finite) sets is the arithmetic product of the cardinatlities of the factors

Comment: @DerekElkins "It doesn't" would be an acceptable (though surprising) answer, but it would in that case be nice to know how totally unrelated concepts came to bear the same name, especially in a field whose whole enterprise is to produce generalizations of field-specific concepts.

Comment: I mean if you want you could contrive an example where the objects of a category are positive integers and the categorical product of two numbers is their arithmetical product but i'm not sure that is what you are looking for

Comment: The categorical product is a categorification of the arithmetical product, which is a more oblique kind of generalization than the kind you're considering here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The categorical definition of a product is *not* intended to be a generalization of the arithmetic notion of a product.  Rather, it is intended as a generalization of the notion of a Cartesian product of sets (or more complicated structures, like groups, topological spaces, etc.). Specifically, the Cartesian product $A\times B=\{(a,b):a\in A,b\in B\}$ of sets $A$ and $B$ together with the projection maps $p_1:A\times B\to A$ and $p_2:A\times B\to B$ given by $p_1(a,b)=a$ and $p_2(a,b)=b$ is a product in the category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are functions.

Cartesian products of sets, of course, are themselves named after arithmetic products of numbers, since they are closely related.  Specifically, if $A$ is a finite set with $a$ elements and $B$ is a finite set with $b$ elements, then the set $A\times B$ has $a\cdot b$ elements.